# How to Update multiple tables with foreign keys using LINQ expression ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I am new to programming, and I have been trying to update multiple tables using LINQ expressions,

```
using (ADBEntities _ADBEntities = new ADBEntities())
{
    try
    {
        tblPerson _Person = new tblPerson();
        _Person.Id = PersonDetails.Id;
        _Person.Firstname = PersonDetails.Firstname;
        _Person.LastName = PersonDetails.LastName;
        _Person.DOB = PersonDetails.DOB;
        _Person.SSN = PersonDetails.SSN;

        var updatePersonDetails = _IPersonRepository.Update(_Person);

        if (updatePersonDetails != null)
        {   
            tblAddress _Address = new tblAddress();
            _Address.PersonId = updatePersonDetails.Id;
            var updateAddressDetails = _ADBEntities.tblAddresses.Find(_Address.PersonId);
            _Address.Id = updateAddressDetails.Id;
            _Address.Address = PersonDetails.Address;

            _ADBEntities.Entry(updateAddressDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(_Address);
            _ADBEntities.SaveChanges(); 

            if (updateAddressDetails != null)
            {
                tblEmail _Email = new tblEmail();
                _Email.PersonId = updateAddressDetails.PersonId;
                var updateEmailDetails = _ADBEntities.tblEmails.Find(_Email.PersonId);
                _Email.Id = updateEmailDetails.Id;
                _Email.Email = PersonDetails.Email;

                _ADBEntities.Entry(updateEmailDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(_Email);
                _ADBEntities.SaveChanges();

                if (updateEmailDetails != null)
                {
                    tblPhone _Phone = new tblPhone();
                    _Phone.PersonId = updateEmailDetails.Id;
                    var updatePhoneDetails = _ADBEntities.tblPhones.Find(_Phone.PersonId);
                    _Phone.Id = updatePhoneDetails.Id;
                    _Phone.PhoneNo = PersonDetails.PhoneNo;

                    _ADBEntities.Entry(updatePhoneDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(_Phone);
                    _ADBEntities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked fine at the beginning, but now it throws an "object null reference" exception.

Tables are

```
tblPerson
tblAddress
tblPhone
tblEmail
```

Comment: Hello Duminda, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know what line it's receiving the `object null reference` on? Are you using Visual Studio, such that you have the ability to walk through the logic to determine what values your variables are set to at runtime?

Comment: One thing that jumps out here: You consistently check for nulls _after_ first dereferencing the object. E.g., you call `updateAddressDetails.Id` but then a few lines later check to see if `updateAddressDetails != null`. Those are in disagreement. The latter may never happen—but, if so, there's no need to check for it. If it _can_ happen, the null check should be sooner. Also, if those null checks are important—and I assume that they are—you don't have one for `updatePhoneDetails`. Since you're dealing with a `NullReferenceException`, those would be my immediate suspicions.

Comment: `_Address.Id = updateAddressDetails.Id;` this line throws an _object null reference_ . some how i managed to solve the issue. the thing is, at the beginning it used to work fine and the next day here comes the problem. what i cannot understand is how it comes success at one stage and later crashes into exceptions.

Comment: Generally, in a case like this, I'd assume that something changed in the database. For example, if the address for the current user was deleted, then this would be an expected exception, even though the code hadn't changed.

Comment: In my case that assumption is not still possible, cause i used cascade delete where i only delete the user and the relevant data to the user to be deleted as well. And i am pretty sure that i didn't delete any tuple from my address table either.

Answer (score 0):

You do not Test your "Find", if it is successfull. Probably this is null.
The pattern you use to update an Item is kind of weired, I give you an example of your innermost update.

```
if (updateEmailDetails != null)
{
    tblPhone _Phone  = _ADBEntities.tblPhones.Find(updateEmailDetails.Id);
    if (_Phone != null)
       _Phone.PhoneNo = PersonDetails.PhoneNo;
}
```

That's all
The SaveChanges you can call at the end, once for all updates

```
 _ADBEntities.SaveChanges();
```

What you have done with creating a new entry is sometimes done, to update an entry, without fetching it first from the Database. But you do Fetch it (with Find). In this case you can go the simple default path.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I got it done by taking all ids of the four tables to view and back to controller, and by repositories to the database.